# Why is absolutely positioned element still in hover scope even though it is visually detached from parent area?

Tags: css, css-position, absolute

I have a simple question over CSS's relative-absolute relationship.

Here's simple example.

HTML:

```
<div class="relative">
    relative area
    <div class="absolute">I am relative area's son. Hover over me! my bg-color changes!</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.absolute {
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    background-color:tomato;
    position: absolute;
    left: 120%;
        top: 0;
}
.relative {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 200px;
}
.relative:hover .absolute {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

https://codepen.io/nori2tae/pen/ZXgMjZ

When I hover over `.absolute` its background color changes.

This shows that though it is **visually** detached from parent area(`.relative`), as long as a child element(`.absolute`) **semantically** belongs to its parent, browser thinks mouse pointer is also on `.absolute`, right?

Therefore hover over `.absolute` also means `.relative:hover`?

And is this so called hoisting?

Someone pls clear the fog over my head.

Comment: **Visually** is a thing and **DOM struture** is another thing. Applying CSS won't affect how the dom/event/etc works. The dom remain the same and the element is always a child of its parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be "visually" detached but to the browser DOM parser still sees your page a bunch of HTML tag. Since the CSS did not change the DOM model the Browser still thinks the absolutely positioned element is still inside its parent element.

Now since browser is responsible for handle such mouse events you get the mentioned behavior.

Its called trickling or capturing.. (different terms for the same thing)

[Hoisting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) is a different concept in javascript (Eg. function and variable declarations are moved to the top during compilation

Comment: Trickling , capturing... never heard of them before, but I get the picture.

Answer (score 0):

```
.relative:hover .absolute {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

I understand your css like so: When hover on `.relative`, make its child `.absolute` change background. And it does just that (because `.absolute` is the child of `.relative`). I don't see what's wrong here?

The reason you hover over `.absolute` and still get the background change is because in fact you're hovering over `.relative`.